# I forgot an important condition in my question, but the question already has answers. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492690/finding-two-group-elements-x-y-in-a-finite-group-such-that-xy-is-greater-t) group theory question and recieved answers, but unfortunately I had forgotten to add another condition which makes the question much more difficult.

Would it acceptable to ask another question with the additional condition, or should I just let this one go?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can ask another Question with the additional restriction (linking of course to the earlier Question for context, as appropriate).

Answer (score 8):

It is unfair to those who answered your question to change it now to a different question. So, ask a new question, with the extra assumption and a link to the previous question (as I did [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3395872/must-a-continuous-non-constant-and-periodic-functions-have-a-smallest-period)).

Comment: I'd recommend adding links in *both* directions, from new question to old, and from old question to new.

Answer (score 7):

Unless

1. the omission made the question trivial, and
2. you didn't see it within a few minutes

it is probably better to ask a different question. If there were only one answer, an option would also be to ask for the opinion of the answerer whether they mind updating their answer. When looking for examples of some phenomenon such an update may not tax the answerer unduly, and the overall quality of the material on the site is enhanced by having a better question and an answer addressing several cases.

If the omission made the question trivial, the answerers should have IMO  checked before posting. If an answer was posted too soon, particularly within the five minute grace window the system gives to all the askers, then they have IMO no basis to their complaints (opinions may vary here).